# How can I use the MIDI-CSV program on Windows

Tags: console, exe, midi

I chose to use MIDI-CSV to convert some MIDI files into CSVs. I downloaded the main .exe-files as a ZIP form the site (https://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/midicsv/#Download), but I can't get them to work. If I execute them, only a console pops up. Is anyone familiar with the syntax for converting files in MIDI-CSV (and CSV-MIDI) under Windows?

I tried to kind of use the command that was explained of the site:

midicsv [ -u -v ] [ infile [ outfile ] ]

The only problem is: It doesn't work. I tried many versions of it, with and without the square brackets.

```
midicsv [ -u -v ] [ infile [ outfile ] ]
csvmidi [ -u -v -x -z ] [ infile [ outfile ] ]
```

are the ones that are explained on the site.

I don't receive any results by entering these, I just get kicked out of the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By sheer coincidence I just happened to try fourmilab's midicsv myself.

I'm giving you my workflow.
No doubt oodles of other ways are available, this one happens to be convenient for me.

Let's say the file midicsv.exe is in the following location in the directory tree:

C:\Users\me\software\fourmilab\

So to invoke midicsv.exe the full path is:

C:\Users\me\software\fourmilab\midicsv.exe

In your case replace as needed.
(For robustness: avoid a space in that path. The command prompt processing is thrown off by any space in the path.)

Rather than first opening a command prompt window, and using that command prompt window, I put the command to invoke the midicsv.exe file in a plain text file that I save with the extension .bat

To edit the plain text file I use Microsoft Notepad.
(A word processor such as Microsoft Word tends to make the file not plain text, so do use an editor that lets you ensure the file is plain text.)

So this just worked for me:
to convert example.mid to example.csv I created a plain text file with the following command:

C:\Users\me\software\fourmilab\midicsv.exe example.mid example.csv

I saved that file in the same directory as the intended source file so I don't have to direct to the source file; the source file is right there in the directory.
(For the filename 'midicsv.bat' is an obvious choice)

I execute that .bat file by right-clicking and clicking the option 'Open'.
Midicsv.exe then converts that source file, and saves the result as example.csv

I find that using a .bat file saves me typing. If I want to convert several files I edit the .bat file for each conversion.